# Ansible using values of an array as a key to loop through a dictionary that contains multiple values

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I'm trying to create directories based on what groups they belong to and what the user defines in the variable.

```
[web20int]
server1
server2

[web20ext]
server3

[app01dev]
server1


certdir:
    
  web20int:
    - intwiki
    - intblogs

  web20ext:
    - wiki
    - xblogs

  app01dev:
    - app01dev


---
  - name: Set App Name Key List
    set_fact:
      ckeys: "{{ certdir.keys()|list }}"

  - name: Get Group Names
    debug:
      msg: "{{ group_names }} "

  - name: Get Cert App Names
    debug:
      msg: item
    loop: "{{ ckeys }}"

  - name: Setting Union between Group Names and Cert App Names
    set_fact:
      union_key: "{{ ckeys | intersect(group_names) }}"

  - name: Result of union
    debug:
       var: union_key
```

This is where i don't understand how to do a nested loop or use jini2 templating.
I want to loop through the union_key array and then loop through certdir
and get the list of values to put into another array

```
  - name: create cert directory for app
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: directory
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0755
    loop: "{{ <SOME ARRAY THAT CONTAINS THE DIRECTORY NAMES }}"
```

Example, server1 belongs to groups:
[web20int]
[app01dev]

Therefore I want the array to contain:
intwiki intblogs app01dev

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`map` the `extract` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables):

```
union_key | map('extract', certdir)
```

But this will give you a list of list, so you then need to apply the `flatten` filter:

```
loop: "{{ union_key | map('extract', certdir) | flatten }}"
```

(You may also need to use the `list` filter if `flatten` gives an iterable instead of a list)

BTW, the variable name and the task name are talking about 'union', but you are doing an 'intersection'.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm.  Thanks i think i was trying union first, then switched to intersect.

Comment: Also i didn't need to use a list filter, what you wrote did the trick

Comment: Think about accepting the answer if it solved your question.